# Why this code compiles in VS? ("extra" comma)

Tags: c++, comma-operator

The line below is inside a for loop. If the method fails, it needs to break. CATEGORY_1 is an enum. I added this enum as a new parameter to AddToList method with a default value. If you see closely below, I actually made the mistake of putting the comma and the enum outside the parameter list of the function. This compiles perfectly fine with VS2010. So I had a hard time finding that that the default value was being passed for that parameter instead of CATEGORY_1.
Does anyone know why this succeeds?

```
if (! AddToList(obj1, (unsigned int) Val), CATEGORY_1)
{
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, the comma isn't just a separator; it can also be an operator.  That comma is an operator.  The comma operator evaluates the first expression, discards the result, then evaluates the second expression and yields its result.

```
!AddToList(obj1, (unsigned int) Val) , CATEGORY_1
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^
First expression                       Second expression
```

[Of course, the comma operator, like most other operators, can be overloaded, and if an overload is used here, the semantics could be different.  This is the behavior of the built-in comma operator.]

Comment: will the not operator be applied or not?

Comment: To be clear, the first expression James refers to is `!AddToList(obj1, (unsigned int) Val)`, and the second expression is `CATEGORY_1`

Comment: @Sriram Subramanian : No, the comma operator has the lowest operator of any operator. So, the not will apply to `AddToList`, not to `CATEGORY_1`.

Comment: @Sriram:  Yes, the `!` is evaluated but it has no meaning since the result is discarded.

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator will simply discard the result of the first expression and evaluate the value of the second expression. So in this case, if `bool(CATEGORY_1) == true` then the `if` would never evaluate; conversely, if `bool(CATEGORY_1) == false` then the `if` would always evaluate. In neither case would it matter what `AddToList` returned.